# ¿Problemas con un ListSelectionListener?

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un problema con mi  ListSelectionListener tengo un JList donde tengo nombres de varios archivos al seleccionar el nombre de un archivo muestro la información que contiene dicho archivo, selecciono un segundo archivo y me vuelve a mostrar la información del primer archivo seleccionado, si selecciono un tercer archivo ahora me muestra la información del segundo archivo seleccionado  no se porque esta pasando esto muestro el código de mi escuchas:

```
 class Esc_lista implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {

            if (!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                scan.cargarArchivo(scan.getfilename(lse.getFirstIndex()));//Abrir el archivo, cargar encabezados y cargar datos
                String [] temp = scan.getHeaders();
                tm.setColumnIdentifiers(temp);
                for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
                tm.addRow(scan.cargarDatos ()); }
                tm.addRow(new String [] {"Totales","","",""+scan.total_c,""+scan.total_d,""+scan.total_r});
                DefaultTableCellRenderer cellrenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                cellrenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(cellrenderer);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(cellrenderer);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(cellrenderer);
                name.setText(scan.getfilename(lse.getFirstIndex()));
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Haces, en alguna parte, limpieza de tabla cada vez que se produce el evento?

Comment: no, no lo hago me podrias explicar como hacerla

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo sencillo para que lo adaptes a tu código.

El toque mágico sería el **modelo.setRowCount(0);**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class EventoTabla {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Ventana();
    }   
}
class Ventana extends JFrame{

    public Ventana() {
        setTitle("Ventana con Tablas");
        setSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
        setLocation(300, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel lamina =new JPanel();
        lamina.setLayout(null);
        dtmTabEvent =new DefaultTableModel();
        tablaEvento =new JTable(dtmTabEvent);
        dtmTabEvent.addColumn("Nombre de archivos");       
        fila =new Object[1];//solo una columna
        cargarModelTabEvent();
        //agrego acción de escucha con clase anónima por sencillez
        tablaEvento.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                    //obtenemos valor de celda seleccionada, esta forma solo es válida cuando
                    //existe solo una columna.
                    String str = (String) dtmTabEvent.getValueAt(tablaEvento.getSelectedRow(), 0);
                    cargarModelTabMostr(str);
                }
            }

        });
        JScrollPane jsTabEvent =new JScrollPane(tablaEvento);//contenedor con barra desplazamiento
        jsTabEvent.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 100);
        lamina.add(jsTabEvent);

        dtmTabMostr =new DefaultTableModel();
        tablaMostrar =new JTable(dtmTabMostr);
        dtmTabMostr.addColumn("Descripción");
        JScrollPane jsTabMostr =new JScrollPane(tablaMostrar);//contenedor con barra desplazamiento
        jsTabMostr.setBounds(300, 10, 150, 100);
        lamina.add(jsTabMostr);

        add(lamina);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private DefaultTableModel dtmTabEvent;
    private JTable tablaEvento;
    private DefaultTableModel dtmTabMostr;
    private JTable tablaMostrar;

    private Object fila[];//se puede usar misma variable para ambas tablas

    private void cargarModelTabEvent(){
        limpiarModelTabEvent();//limpiamos antes de llenar

        String str1 ="Archivo a";
        String str2 ="Archivo b";
        String str3 ="Archivo c";
        fila[0] =str1;
        dtmTabEvent.addRow(fila);
        fila[0] =str2;
        dtmTabEvent.addRow(fila);
        fila[0] =str3;
        dtmTabEvent.addRow(fila); 
    }
    private void limpiarModelTabEvent(){
        dtmTabEvent.setRowCount(0);
    }

    private void cargarModelTabMostr(String str){
        //fijate que si comentas la linea siguiente se irán acumulando
        limpiarModelTabMostr();//limpiamos antes de llenar.

        fila[0] =str;        
        dtmTabMostr.addRow(fila); 
    }
    private void limpiarModelTabMostr(){
        dtmTabMostr.setRowCount(0);
    }
}
```